# PHP: preg_replace to match some numbers but not others

Tags: php, regex

So I've been working on a little project to write a syntax highlighter for a game's scripting language. It's all gone off without a hitch, except for one part: the numbers.

Take these lines for example

`(5:42) Set database entry {healthpoints2} to the value 100.`

`(5:140) Move the user to position (29,40) on the map.`

I want to highlight that 100 on the end, without highlighting the (5:42) or the 2 in the braces. The numbers won't always be in the same place, and there won't always only be one number.

I basically need a regexp to say:

"Match any numbers that aren't anywhere between {} and don't match the (#:#) pattern."

I've been at this for a day and a half now and I'm pulling out my hair trying to figure it out. Help with this would be greatly appreciated!
I've already looked at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), and tried playing around with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/), but i'm just not getting it :c

Edit: By request, here's some more lines copied right from the script editor.

`(0:7) When somebody moves into position (**10** fhejwkfhwjekf **20**,`

`(0:20) When somebody rolls exactly **10** on **2** dice of **6** sides,`

`(0:31) When somebody says {...},`

`(3:3) within the diamond (**5**,**10**) - **20** //// **25**,`

`(3:14) in a line starting at (#, #) and going # more spaces northeast.`

`(5:10) play sound # to everyone who can see (#,#).`

`(5:14) move the user to (#,#) if there's nobody already there.`

`(5:272) set message ~msg to be the portion of message ~msg from position # to position #.`

`(5:302) take variable %var and add # to it.`

`(5:600) set database entry {...} about the user to #.`

`(5:601) set database entry {...} about the user named {...} to #.`

Comment: What do you mean by 'highlight'? Please provide at least one example of an input AND the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might kick yourself when you see this solution...

Assuming this desired number will always be used in a sentence, it should always have a space preceding it.

```
$pattern = '/ [0-9]+/s';
```

If the preceding space isn't always present, let me know and I'll update the answer.

---

Here's the updated regex to match the 2 examples in your question:

```
$pattern = '/[^:{}0-9]([0-9,]+)[^:{}0-9]/s';
```

---

3nd update to account for your question revisions:

```
$pattern = '/[^:{}0-9a-z#]([0-9]+[, ]?[0-9]*)[^:{}0-9a-z#]/s';
```

So you don't highlight the number in things like

> {update 29 testing}

you might want to pre strip the braces, like so:

```
$pattern = '/[^:{}0-9a-z#]([0-9]+[, ]?[0-9]*)[^:{}0-9a-z#]/s';
$str = '(0:7) Hello {update 29 testing} 123 Rodger alpha charlie 99';
$tmp_str = preg_replace('/{[^}]+}/s', '', $str);
preg_match($pattern, $tmp_str, $matches);
```

Comment: Unfortunately like I just edited in the post as an afterthought, sometimes the numbers will be in (#,#) settings, or with periods, or with any other number of strange things around them. - The purpose of this script is for hilighting user-submitted code, so I'm trying to make it work with any weirdness they typed in.

Comment: Ok, please can you post a more extensive set of examples? I need to see the full range of what should be matched...

Comment: Just added a bunch more lines, that pretty much covers most of it. The only other thing to note is the text is completely ignored by the script parser, so some people modify it or erase it. You only need the (#:#) trigger and the parameters.

Comment: Try the latest example. Seems to be holding up well.

Comment: Not quite - heres an example in action. http://dreclindreams.v4.net/dsbin/?ds=1o6m2b4390mps

Comment: When you say "You only need the (#:#) trigger and the parameters", what do you mean by "parameters" ? Can you please bold the specific sections you want extracted in a few of your examples?

Comment: I should also note that the coordinates are only in brackets for visual appeal, using "20 39" is the same as "(20, 39)"

Comment: Bolding doesn't seem to be behaving. Or I'm doing it wrong, haha. Anyway I "bolded" some of the numbers as an example: it doesnt matter what sort of gibberish is around the numbers, as long as they're there and in the right order. "(5:10) 39 18" is also completely valid here.

Comment: It's better but still not totally behaving - {&#9835; This dream uses <b>Music</b> and <b>Sounds</b>! &#9834;} - the numbers in that are still showing up blue, and theres an {update 29 testing} bit where the 29 is highlighted. As a side note, in the coordinates the brackets themselves aren't supposed to be colored, only the numbers inside them. (excluding the comma, as well)

Comment: I've updated the regex to stop your 1st example. But for the second one you're moving to complexity that may justify parsing the strings instead of just matching bits with regex. I'll add a 2-step brute force solution in my answer though, 1 sec...

Comment: Yeah I was wondering if parsing would really be the best option. The highlighting for all the other bits was easily done with simple regexp matches but the numbers have been a major headache.

Comment: I think that will work! I didn't even think about stripping the braces :D thanks a ton man haha

Comment: np. Would you mind accepting my answer then? It's the green tick under the voting arrows, next to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+,\s?\d+)|(?<![\(\{:]|:\d)\d+(?![\)\}])
```

http://regexr.com?30omd

Would this work?

Comment: Not quite, it's still making the numbers inside of {} highlighted.